# Acentuação em select

Tags: mysql

Estou tentando exportar alguns registros do banco de dados Mysql para Excel,
mas quando abre a planilha onde tem acentuação aparece o sinal �� como que eu posso resolver isto?

Comment: Qual é charset do banco de dados e do seu arquivo php?

Comment: O problema é de codificação. Provavelmente sua base está em `UTF-8` e o Excel sempre usa `ISO-8859-1`. Não lembro se tem alguma configuração do cliente do MySQL para converter os dados, mas você pode tentar usar talvez o Notepad++ para converter o *encoding* antes de colocar no Excel.

Comment: Coloque o código que gera o arquivo do excel.